# Best pattern (combination) for CLI + service singletons (Java FX)

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-line-interface

I want to create a cli with JavaFx. The commands could something like:

- add foldername
- "+ foldername"
- delete foldername
- "- foldername"
- rename oldfoldername newfoldername
  etc.

so some commands have the same task.
I operate on the file system, I want to use singleton objects.
Is there a good pattern (combination) to interpret the commands with there different parameters and get a JavaFx service to do the work in a io-thread?

Factory pattern, command pattern and interpretor pattern alone are in my optinion not the best way to do the task and I don't get a good combination of these pattern.

I hope somebody can help me.

THX

Comment: 1. Create your own Grammar. 2. Use `Task` to execute long-complex operations.

Comment: Is there any kind of framework to create my own grammar? Inside Java or an external framework? And do you mean the JavaFx-Task? Why not the Java-Fx Service?